# ng repeat json parse show empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pug

I had the array of objects string from a list of array. I convert object string to object using method of `JSON.parse` the object but it shows empty within ng-repeat.

**Jade**

```
.item.col-md-4(ng-repeat='p in searchData | filter: paginate | orderBy: sortKey ')
   // `p` is a object of string, for example "{id:2, name:'abel'}";
   - var property = JSON.parse("{{ p }}"); // Error at this line
   +AddPropertyCard(property)
```

**SearchData**

```
[{id:0, name:"abel"},{id:1, name:"julia"}]
```

**Error**

> var property = JSON.parse("");
>
> Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1

Comment: Can you show us your JSON?

Comment: It seems that `p` is empty, chehck `p` 's value first.

Comment: @leaf the {{ p }} returns object.

Comment: this won't work, jade is trying to parse the property on the server, not the client, but the ng-repeat isn't expanded on the server.  besides that, you don't **need** `JSON.parse` here anyway;  the ng-repaeat should already have individual `p` objects, `{{p.id}}` and `{{p.name}}` should output directly.

Comment: more than likely, you just need `+AddPropertyCard(p)`, and the line with `JSON.parse` can go away completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 1** :

Variable 'p' Seems to be object.

You have to access it using dot notations.
Like **{{p.id}}** or **{{p.name}}**. This will show respective values.

---

**JSON.parse expects object string in order to Parse it.**

```
// Lets create a simple Object in javascript
var notStringObj = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York"
};
console.log("JavaScript Object", notStringObj);

// Lets stringify (Convert in string) the object
var stringObj = JSON.stringify(notStringObj);
console.log("JavaScript Stringified Object", stringObj);

// Following is code to decode this object

// This will give you result you are expecting i.e. JavaScript Object
var obj1 = JSON.parse(stringObj);

// This will throw error - Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
// Because this was plain object not a string
// JSON.parse expects object string in order to Parse it
var obj2 = JSON.parse(notStringObj)
```

Comment: It doesn't show error anymore. With JSON.stringify, it shows empty. The p variable has the object from ng-repeat. But shows nothing

Comment: @Abel Chun 'p' is a object. you have to access it with dot notation. try accessing like {{p.id}}, {{p.name}}. It won't show any error then